# Не могу отобразить значение переменной в массив label WinForms

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

нужно чтобы 5 label выводили номера от 0 до 4 , но что-то не так не могу понять в чем дело.

```
        {
            tba = gcnew cli::array<TextBox^ >(5);
            lb = gcnew cli::array<Label^>(5);
            for (int i = 0; i<tba->Length; i++)
            {
                tba[i] = gcnew TextBox();
                lb[i] = gcnew Label();
                tba[i]->Location = System::Drawing::Point(15, 75 + 25 * i);
                lb[i]->Location = Drawing::Point(150, 75 + 25 * i);
                tba[i]->Size = System::Drawing::Size(200, 20);
                lb[i]->Size= System::Drawing::Size(50, 20);
                tba[i]->TabIndex = i + 2;
                lb[i]->TabIndex = i+3;
                lb[i]->Text = i.ToString();
                this->Controls->Add(tba[i]);
                this->Controls->Add(lb[i]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Координаты перекрываются. Лейбл находится под текстбоксом.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov , действительно ,спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Координаты перекрываются. Лейбл находится под текстбоксом.

Я просто подвинул по x правее и циферки появились)